# Automatically add users to the wordpress multisite network subsite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite network, is there any way to automatically add users in the subsites when i add users in any of the subsite in the multisite network.

The site is restricted from public access its an organizational intranet site. Now the users can view the subsites in single login, but I want to restrict some parts of the site from subscibers.

I have added a function to append user role in the body, only the site where the user is registered - the respective role is displaying, When i add manually that user his role class is appending.

I'm using the following code:

```
add_filter('body_class','add_role_to_body');
function add_role_to_body($classes) {
$current_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
$user_role = array_shift($current_user->roles);
$classes[] = 'role-'. $user_role;
return $classes;
}
```

the result is:

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in group-blog **role-subscriber** website-1">
```

In other sites this users role is not appending because he is not a user in that subsite.
in this scenario, the result is:

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in group-blog **role-** website-1">
```

My main Question is:
Is here any way to **automatically add users** in the subsites when i add users in any of the subsite in the multisite network, or to add automatically in that subsite when the user visit that particular subsite. Or **any function** to check the role of the user from the network sites and append the role class in the body tag.

Comment: A bit confusing explanation, but search for plugins that sync multisite users. I think it will help you.

Comment: In website one were the user is a subscriber `<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in group-blog role-subscriber website-1">`
In website 2 were the user is not in the user list of the subsite `<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in group-blog role- website-2">`

Comment: I need role-subscriber to be appended in website-2 also, any way?